# Javascript Find the next occurrence of a "letter"

Tags: javascript, string

I just need an idea!

If I have a string `"string1, values, string2, values, string3, values, ....."`

How can I get the index of the second string? why? because I want divide this string into

```
"string1, values"
"string2, values"
...
```

by using `substring(0, index-1 of the second string)` and so on.

To be more clear I have

""a", 4, 2, 2, 4, 5, "b", 6, 4, 3, 6, 7, "x", 5, 6, 7, 8, .... "

I want the "second" occurrence of a letter

Comment: I believe you're looking for LETTERS, not ALPHABETS.

Comment: sorry! it's stressful I'm not able to think anymore

Comment: so the commas do not matter at all? Because it looks like you lost a comma in the process

Comment: how about split it to array by comma and then go through the array each by each check the type of value and do what you want to do?

Comment: sorry corrected!, I can split by comma but I thought javascript might have something more ...

Comment: Are you in control of the string passed in?

Comment: yes I do have control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're looking for, maybe this?

```
str = '"a", 4, 2, 2, 4, 5, "b", 6 4 3 6 7, "x", 5 6 7 8"'
obj = {}, last = ""
str.replace(/(\d+)|(\w+)/g, function(_, d, w) { 
     d ? obj[last].push(parseInt(d)) : obj[last = w] = [] 
})
```

This populates an object `obj` like this:

```
{"a":[4,2,2,4,5],"b":[6,4,3,6,7],"x":[5,6,7,8]}
```